# How to show $\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\pi/2$

Tags: improper-integrals

How to show that

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

The problem is that I don't know what is

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}{\mathrm{arcsec}\ x}$$

Comment: are you sure you want the upper limit to be $\infty?$

Comment: That's given in question

Comment: for $x > 1, \sqrt{1-x^2}$ is not real. and at $x = 0,$ the integral does not converge.

Comment: @user210709 $$\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}} \neq \sec^{-1}(x)+C$$ but $$\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}= \sec^{-1}(x)+C$$

Comment: Got it. but Does $\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\pi/2$?

Comment: It should be $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}} = \pi/2$

Comment: $\mathrm{arcsec} \,x$ does not exist at $x=0$

Comment: can you edit your question to reflect the changes suggested in the answers and comments.

Comment: The integral can be written with $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and doesn't need to be changed to $\sqrt{x^2-1}$. The only issue is the bounds which should say either $(-1,\infty)$ or $(1,\infty)$ since the Principal Value of $(-1,\infty)$ is $-i\pi/2$ and the integral of $(1,\infty)$ is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \sec^{-1} x$ $\mathbf{is}$ $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

$$\sec^{-1} x = \cos^{-1}\frac{1}{x}$$

And $\cos^{-1} 0 = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1} }= -\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right)+C$$

Answer (score 0):

Begin by writing
\begin{eqnarray} 
y=\sqrt{x^2-1}\\ y^2=x^2-1, \ x=\sqrt{1+y^2}\\ ydy=xdx\\ y(1)=0,\ y(\infty)=\infty. 
\end{eqnarray}
Then re-write as
\begin{eqnarray}
I &=& \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dy}{1+y^{2}} \\
  &=& \tan^{-1}y|_{0}^{\infty} \\
  &=& \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you intended to write 
$$ 
\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
First note that
$$ 
\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx= \int_1^\infty \frac{x}{x^2\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx
$$
Let $u=\sqrt{x^2-1}$, then $du=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx$. So now
$$ 
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{u^2+1}du
$$
$$=\lim\limits_{\beta\to \infty} \arctan \beta- \lim\limits_{\alpha\to 0^+} \arctan \alpha
$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{2}- 0= \frac{\pi}{2}
$$
As already mentioned, your original integral does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

When evaluating integrals containing $\sqrt{x^2\pm a^2}$, one of the basic substitutions is $x=a\sinh t$ $($for the case with $+)$ or $x=a\cosh t$ $($for the case with $-)$. Then use $\cosh^2t-\sinh^2t=1$, together with $\sinh't=\cosh t$ and $\cosh't=\sinh t$. Also, a second substitution, $u=e^t$ might sometimes also be in order, to reduce the integrand to a rational function.

Comment: Also, you asked about the value of $\sec^{-1}\infty$. Since $\sec x=\dfrac1{\cos x}$, the question is equivalent to $\dfrac1{\cos x}\to\infty\iff\cos x=0^+$.

Comment: See also [hyperbolic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function).